# nginx: redirect subfolder to subdomain

Tags: nginx, redirect, subdomain, directory

I'm trying to redirect a subfolder to a subdomain in nginx. I want http://example.com/~meow/ to be redirected to http://meow.example.com/. I tried the following:

```
location ~ ^/\~meow/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://meow.example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

But it doesn't work. It gets caught by my location block for user directories:

```
location ~ ^/~([^/]+)/(.+\.php)$ {
    [...]
}

and

location ~ ^/\~([^/]+)/(.*)$ {
    [...]
}
```

So, how would I do this? Oh, and I only want /~meow/ to be redirected. All other user directories should not be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using nested `location` like this

```
location ~ ^/\~([^/]+)/(.*)$ {
  location ~ ^/\~meow/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://meow.example.com$1 permanent;     
  }
  [...]
}
```

Comment: +1 for nested. These things have a way of growing out of proportion over time and keeping it nested means you're not scratching your head what you missed that prevents it from working.

Answer (score 6):

A static location would be more efficient for what you're asking.  If you read the four rules at http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location , you'll see that a locaion ^~ will not be overridden by a regex location.  You also seem to want to strip the leading /~meow while redirecting.  The correct approach would be:

```
location ^~ /~meow/ {
  rewrite ^/~meow(.*) http://meow.example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

As an aside, there's no reason to capture the entire uri when rewriting.  The current uri is already saved in $uri.

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://meow.example.com$1 permanent;
```

and

```
rewrite ^ http://meow.example.com$uri permanent;
```

will *always* produce the same result, and the second rewrite is more efficient, since it's a short circuited match and already contains what you're trying to capture anyway.

Comment: Excellent with the one liners! + Repped

Answer (score 1):

Regexp locations are checked in the order of their appearance in the configuration file and the first positive match is used. Which means, your `location ~ ^/\~meow/(.*)$` must be above other two locations in the configuration file.