# Nginx redirect folder to subdomain

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I'm trying to configure a redirect on Nginx from a folder to a subdomain.
I've tried already [Nginx redirect: folder to external domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/397417/nginx-redirect-folder-to-external-domain) and [Nginx rewrite rule (subdirectory to subdomain)](https://serverfault.com/questions/396034/nginx-rewrite-rule-subdirectory-to-subdomain) and [nginx: redirect subfolder to subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/269881/nginx-redirect-subfolder-to-subdomain). Nothing works.

The problem, are simple. I have a Apache configured with this line:

> RedirectPermanent /asd http://asd.domain.com/

Now, I'm trying to replicate this on a Nginx.
Every configuration I've tried, have the same problem:

> If I go to http://www.domain.com/asd/, they redirect me to http://asd.domain.com/asd/.
>
> If I go to http://www.domain.com/asd/index, they redirect to http://asd.domain.com/index.

I need to delete the sub-folder in all cases, for me, the first one are incorrect. How can I configure nginx for in first case, go to http://asd.domain.com/?

The rules are applied after root parameter. The config are:

```
server {
  listen --
  server_name --
  root --
  <> INSERT RULE HERE
  access_log --
  error_log --
  include - (A file with php configurations).
}
```

Some examples of tried rules:

> rewrite ^/asd/(.*) http://asd.domain.com/$1 permanent;
>
> rewrite ^/asd(.*) http://asd.domain.com/$1 permanent;
>
> rewrite ^/asd(.*) http://asd.domain.com$1 permanent;
>
> location ^~ /asd/ { rewrite ^/asd/(.*) http://asd.domain.com/$1 permanent; }
>
> location ^~ /asd/ { rewrite ^/asd(.*) http://asd.domain.com/$1 permanent; }
>
> location ^~ /asd/ { rewrite ^/asd(.*) http://asd.domain.com$1 permanent; }
>
> Also, location variation with "location ~ ^/asd/(.*)" or "location ~ ^/asd(.*)"

Thanks,

Comment: given that the links you provided have suitable answers can you provide the configs that you have that dont work

Comment: I've included some configurations I've tried to do. Note, the problem are ONLY on the first case, when I go to www.domain.com/asd/. There's no problem when I go to a page inside the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were close with `rewrite ^/asd/(.*) http://asd.domain.com/$1 permanent;`

Per the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html):

> If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the
>   previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is
>   undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string
>   avoids having them appended

But you might need to add a **?**, and just for good practice that ending **$** as such:

```
rewrite ^/asd/(.*)$ http://asd.domain.com/$1? permanent;
```

Comment: Still fail on Firefox, but, I've tried with iE and these solution works correctly. I think the problem are now on firefox cache. Thanks.